# Quiz that I made in python won't work

Tags: python

I have recently made a quiz in my computer science lesson but for some reason it did not work, I am new to programming and I was wondering maybe you could help me, I know that it will be something simple but as I said, I am new to this. I have only copied 4 questions out of the 8 I have made but for some reason it ignores the IF statement and goes straight to the else statement.    The code is the following:

```
score=0
print("Welcome the the general knowledge quiz")
your_name = input("What is your name?: ")

input("Press Enter to Start the Quiz!")

print("1) Who presents Pointless?")
answer = input()
if answer == ["Alexander Armstong", "alexander armstrong", "ALEXANDER  
ARMSTRONG"]:
    print("Well done", your_name)
    score = score+1
else:
    print("Sorry, the answer was Alexander Armstrong")
print("Your score is", score)


print("2) Who presents I'm a celeb, get me out of here?")
answer = input()
if answer == ["Ant and Dec", "ant and dec", "ANT AND DEC", "Ant And Dec"]:
    print("Well done", your_name)
    score = score+1
else:
    print("Sorry, the answer was Ant and Dec")
print("Your score is", score)


print("3) What is the capital of England?")
answer = input()
if answer == ["London", "london", "LONDON"]:
    print("Well done", your_name)
    score = score+1
else:
    print("Sorry, the answer was London")
print("Your score is", score)


print("4) Who lives on the White house right now?")
answer = input()
if answer == ["Obama", "obama", "Barack Obama", "barack obama"]:
    print("Well done", your_name)
    score = score+1
else:
    print("Sorry, the answer was Barack Obama")
print("Your score is", score)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
answer = input()
if answer == ["Alexander Armstong", "alexander armstrong", "ALEXANDER  
ARMSTRONG ):
```

Missing quotation mark aside, this if statement will always fail. `input()` always returns a string, but you're checking if it's equal to a list, which can never be true. If you replace `==` with `in`, it will do what you expect.

Also, you should consider using `.lower()` to make the answer into lowercase, then you'd only have one value to check.

Comment: Welcome the the general knowledge quiz
    What is your name?: Jack
    Press Enter to Start the Quiz!
    1) Who presents Pointless?
    Alexander Armstrong
    Sorry, the answer was Alexander Armstrong
    Your score is 0
    2) Who presents I'm a celeb, get me out of here?

Comment: This is what I got with the changes you suggested (They are meant to be in lines but it wont let me.)

Comment: That's because you misspelled `Armstrong` in the first slot in your list. Typos like that are easy to make, which is why I would recommend making the user's input into lower case, and then only checking it against a lower case version of "alexander armstrong". That way there's only one string you can screw up, instead of three, and it will also handle things like "AlExAnDeR aRmStRoNg".

Comment: Thank you so much, there is just one last question where the answer is a number and it wont work.                                                                                          print("7) How old is the Queen?")
answer = input()
answer = int(answer)
if answer == ["90"]:
    print("Well done", your_name)
    score = score+1
else:
    print("Sorry, the answer was 90")
print("Your score is", score)

Comment: It does the exact same thing

Comment: It looks like you're trying to compare a number `int(input())` to a string `"90"`. Either don't convert the input into a number, or make 90 into a number.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is now working fully, I can now show my teacher this. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 1):

There's a hint in the syntax highlighting: you're missing a `"`:

```
if answer == ["Alexander Armstong", "alexander armstrong", "ALEXANDER ARMSTRONG ):
    print("Well done", your_name)
```

There's no `"` after `ARMSTRONG`.